# How to Get Method Name From Action in Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Is there any alternative way to get the method name from an `Action` instead of `Action.Method.Name`

Seems `Action.Method.Name` is not supported in Windows Store Apps and I'm getting following error.

`System.Action<object>` does not contain a definition for `Method` and no extension method `Method` accepting a first argument of type `System.Action<object>` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try making sure you have `System.Reflection` referenced, then use the extension `Delegate.GetMethodInfo()`;

Comment: @NateDiamond,`System.Delegate` does not contain a definition for `GetMethodInfo` with or without `using System.Reflection;`

Comment: It is located in the [`RuntimeReflectionsExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is available in Win8+ and Win Phone 8+.

Comment: @NateDiamond, `RuntimeReflectionsExtensions` is the answer. put it as an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [RuntimeReflectionExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get access to Delegate.GetMethodInfo(). This will give you the method info you desire.